# How to get distinct value from an array of objects containing array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get an array of distinct values from the data structure below. I tried using reduce and object keys with no luck. What can I try next?

**Data:**

```
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "Technologies": ["SharePoint", "PowerApps"]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "Technologies": ["SharePoint", "PowerApps", "SomethingElse"]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "Technologies": ["SharePoint"]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "Technologies": ["PowerApps"]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "Technologies": null
  }
]
```

**Finished result should look like:**

```
var distintValues = ["PowerApps", "SharePoint", "SomethingElse", null]
```

**My attempt:**
https://codepen.io/bkdigital/pen/MWEoLXv?editors=0012

Comment: Does the order of the values in the output matter, or is any order ok?

Comment: Why don't you check index and push it in new array? Have you tried it?

Comment: Your code should not be behind a link. Create a runnable snippet inside your question using the toolbar;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). `.flatMap` allows you to map each object's technology to one resulting array, and the Set allows you to remove the duplicates. With the help of [optional chaining `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), you can also keep the `null` value (so it doesn't throw when accessing `Technologies`) like so:

```js
const data = [{ "id": 1, "Technologies": ["SharePoint", "PowerApps"] }, { "id": 2, "Technologies": ["SharePoint", "PowerApps", "SomethingElse"] }, { "id": 3, "Technologies": ["SharePoint"] }, { "id": 4, "Technologies": ["PowerApps"] }, { "id": 5, "Technologies": null } ];

const res = [...new Set(data.flatMap(obj => obj?.Technologies))];
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[...new Set(
  data
    .map(v => Array.isArray(v.Technologies) ? v.Technologies : [v.Technologies])
    .reduce((t, v) => [...t, ...v], [])
)];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your attempt you tried to do it with reduce so here is how I would do it

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "Technologies": ["SharePoint", "PowerApps"]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "Technologies": ["SharePoint", "PowerApps", "SomethingElse"]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "Technologies": ["SharePoint"]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "Technologies": ["PowerApps"]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "Technologies": null
  }
];

const objAsArray = Object.keys(data) // first we get the keys
  .map(key => data[key]) // then we map them to their value

const technologyMap = objAsArray.reduce((acc, data) => {
  // if the entry has technologies we set the key in the accumulation object to true
  if (data.Technologies) {
    data.Technologies.forEach(tech => acc[tech] = true)
  }
  return acc;
}, {})

// at the very end we get the keys of the accumulation object
const uniqueTechnologies =
  Object.keys(
    technologyMap
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this through JS. Here is my code:

```js
const data = [{
            "id": 1,
            "Technologies": ["SharePoint", "PowerApps"]
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "Technologies": ["SharePoint", "PowerApps", "SomethingElse"]
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "Technologies": ["SharePoint"]
        }, {
            "id": 4,
            "Technologies": ["PowerApps"]
        }, {
            "id": 5,
            "Technologies": null
        }]
        const distintValues = [];
        for (let element of data) {
            if (element.Technologies != null) {
                for (let elem of element.Technologies) {
                    if (!distintValues.includes(elem)) {
                        distintValues.push(elem);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(distintValues);
```